# why 'ls' command printing the directory content multiple times

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have the following shell script in which I want to check the specific directory content on the remote machines and print them in a file.

```
file=serverList.csv
n=0
while [ $n -le 2 ]
do
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2
do
      # echo line is stored in $line
       if echo $f1 | grep -q "xx.xx.xxx";
       then
           ssh user@$f1 ls path/*war_*  > path/$f1.txt < /dev/null; ls path/*zip_* >> path/$f1.txt < /dev/null; 
           ssh user@$f1 ls -d /apps/jetty*_* >> path/$f1.txt < /dev/null; 
       fi
done < "$file"
sleep 15
n=$(( n+1 ))
done
```

I am using this script inside a cron job for every 2 minute as following:

```
*/2 * * * * /path/myscript.sh
```

but somehow I am ending up with the following output file:

```
/apps/jetty/webapps_wars/test_new.war
path/ReleaseTest.static.zip_2020-08-05
path/ReleaseTest.static.zip_2020-08-05
path/ReleaseTest.static.zip_2020-08-05
path/jetty_xx.xx_2020-08-05
path/jetty_new
path/jetty_xx.xx_2020-08-05
path/jetty_new
```

I am not sure why am I getting the files in the list twice, sometimes 3 times. but I execute the shell directly from putty, it works fine. What do I need to change in order to correct this script?

Comment: you use too much `*` wildcards and many `ls` instead of a better filter so you get many similar lines : then both solution *piggy one* filter output ; good one  review you loop & use more regexp & better filename filtering ; you might consider using find (*with -o... -o .... -o ...*) to get your filename list also you will get result both unique & without `ls` who is a bad practice in scripting *for example in your case you see why it is bad*

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
~$ cd tmp
~/tmp$ mkdir test
~/tmp$ cd !$
cd test
~/tmp/test$ mkdir -p apps/jetty/webapp_wars/ && touch apps/jetty/webapp_wars/test_new.war
~/tmp/test$ mkdir path
~/tmp/test$ touch path/{ReleaseTest.static.zip_2020-08-05,jetty_xx.xx_2020-08-05,jetty_new}
~/tmp/test$ cd ..
~/tmp$ listpath=$(find test/path \( -name "*2020-08-05" -o -name "*new" \) )
~/tmp$ listapps=$(find test/apps/  -name "*war" )
~/tmp$ echo ${listpath[@]}" "${listapps[@]} | tr " "  "\n" | sort  > resultfile 
~/tmp$ 
~/tmp$ cat resultfile 
test/apps/jetty/webapp_wars/test_new.war
test/path/jetty_new
test/path/jetty_xx.xx_2020-08-05
test/path/ReleaseTest.static.zip_2020-08-05
~/tmp$ rm -rf test/ && unset listapps && unset listpath && rm resultfile 
~/tmp$
```

This way you get only one result for each pattern you are looking for in your `if...then...else` block of code.

Just adapt the `ssh ..... find` commands and take care of quotes & parentheses but there is the easiest solution, this way you do not have to rewrite the script from scratch.  And be careful on local / remote variables if you use them.

Comment: Plain `find` without a `-maxdepth` will traverse subdirectories, too, which the OP's original code did not do. It's not clear whether or not this is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You really [should not use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) but the fundamental problem is probably that three separate commands with three separate wildcards could match the same file three times.

Also, one of your commands is executed locally (you forgot to put `ssh` etc in front of the second one), so if the wildcard matches on your local computer, that would produce a result which doesn't reflect the situation on the remote server.

Try this refactoring.

```sh
file=serverList.csv
n=0
while [ $n -le 2 ]
do
    while IFS=: read -r f1 f2
    do
        # echo line is stored in $line  <- XXX this is not true
        if echo "$f1" | grep -q "xx.xx.xxx";
        then
            ssh user@$f1 "printf '%s\n' path/*war_* path/*zip_* /apps/jetty*_*" | sort -u >path/"$f1".txt < /dev/null
        fi
    done < "$file"
    sleep 15
    n=$(( n+1 ))
done
```

The `sort` gets rid of any duplicates. This assumes none of your file names contain newlines; if they do, you'd need to use something which robustly handles them (try `printf '%s\0'` and `sort -z` but these are not portable).

`ls` would definitely also accept three different wildcards but like the link above explains, you really never want to use `ls` in scripts.